# How do I get my console application to run a background process on another thread without exiting?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, timer

I am aware that in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) there are three timer types (see *[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)*). I have chosen a threaded timer as the other types can drift if the main thread is busy, and I need this to be reliable.

The way this timer works in the control of the timer is put on another thread so it can always tick along with the work begin completed on the parent thread when it is not busy.

The issue with this timer in a console application is that while the timer is ticking along on another thread the main thread is not doing anything so the application closes.

I tried adding a `while true` loop, but then the main thread is too busy when the timer does go off.

Comment: You can relinquish the clock cycles that are being consumed by the `while true` loop by adding `Thread.Sleep(100)` inside the loop.  There's probably a better way to do all this, though, like creating a Windows Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Barrier that waits until all threads are done. Since there is a main and a counting thread, I have 2 participants. So it will look something like this:

```
 Module Module1
        Dim x As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf tick)
        Dim y As New Threading.Barrier(2)

        Sub Main()
            x.IsBackground = True
            x.Start()
            y.SignalAndWait()
        End Sub

        Sub tick()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
            y.SignalAndWait()
        End Sub
    End Module
```

Comment: Does this really do anything, or is it just a whole lot of ceremony for what amounts to an endless loop with a `Sleep()` call in it?  The [documentation for Threading.Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) states that the Barrier class *"enables multiple tasks to cooperatively work on an algorithm in parallel through multiple phases."*  I don't see "cooperatively," "parallel," or "multiple phases" anywhere in here.

Comment: I actually think this is the very simple and well explaining usage of the Barrier. The main thread and the other thread work cooperatively. Just because it's simple doesn't mean it is not working cooperatively. Another point is, the Barrier takes same amount of code as your "Sleep() in a loop" suggestion, while it fits to more complicated situations(more threads or when each ms matters etc..), with no extra resource cost at all. Thus, using something "blocking" instead of "waiting" seemed more proper way of doing this to me.